# Need to loop a MySql Query by changing a parameter

Tags: mysql, loops

I am very new to mysql scripts , I want to execute this query by incrementing `00:00:00` time to `30` minutes .

something like this

```
Select count(*) 
FROM ctrdb.CTR_LINE_ITEM 
where LOAD_DATE BETWEEN '2016-05-18 00:00:00' AND '2016-05-18 00:30:00' 
order by load_date;

Select count(*) 
FROM ctrdb.CTR_LINE_ITEM 
where LOAD_DATE BETWEEN '2016-05-18 00:30:00' AND '2016-05-18 00:60:00' 
order by load_date;
```

Can you guys please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wan to achieve this in mysql and want to get separate resultset for each query
then you need to run your query in **loop** by using **stored procedure**.

read loop in mysql http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx

or there are not multiple queries then you can use **union** as well

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getdata()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT;

 DECLARE maximum INT; # you can use date as well
 DECLARE startdate  DATE;
 DECLARE enddate  DATE;

 SET x =0;

 SET maximum = 10;
 SET startdate =   '2016-05-18 00:00:00';


 loop_label:  LOOP
    IF  x > 10 THEN 
        LEAVE  loop_label;
    END  IF;
    SET  x = x + 1;
    SET enddate =   startdate   + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
    Select count(*) ,startdate
    FROM ctrdb.CTR_LINE_ITEM 
    where LOAD_DATE BETWEEN '2016-05-18 00:00:00' AND '2016-05-18 00:30:00' 
    order by load_date;
    SET startdate =   startdate   + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;

END LOOP; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me , out and sorry for the late reply